# Rails: call controller action without changing url / redirect to controller index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to have 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons on my page but when clicked, I want to have the appropriate controller action called but without redirecting to the domain/controller/action.

The next and previous actions would pop from a session array that contains ids of what to display.

Is it possible to provide my link: reader_next_path (redirects to localhost/reader/next)
but then have the Reader next method render the index with my specified @instance_variables?

I really don't want to have to create a new template for all of these actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

render "index"
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: I already have a call to render :index in my controller methods, what I'm asking is to not have the url read localhost/reader/next but rather localhost/reader

Comment: Sorry. There might be better way, but how about Ajax call?

Comment: I will look into that, working on figuring out AJAX for simple things right now, could look into this in the near future. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a symbol in this case:

```
render :index
```